# MySQL multiple column sum don't exceed given criteria for each

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with the following problem.

I'm trying to make a small application that has a database of foods where each food item has columns: fat, carbohydrates, proteins, calories and each row in the table is a value per 100 grams

criteria that the user enters are:
for example: 50 fat, 15 carbohydrates, 2000 calories and 200 protein

I would like to retrieve a list where the sum of each column (fat,carbs,protein,calories) in the list does not exceed the criterion

```
+----+---------------------------+------+----------+---------------+----------+
| id | name                      | fats | proteins | carbohydrates | calories |
+----+---------------------------+------+----------+---------------+----------+
|  2 | Pileća prsa, file         |    1 |     24.7 |           0.5 |    112.6 |
|  3 | Janjetina (nemasno)       | 12.7 |     19.7 |           0.3 |    200.1 |
|  4 | Žablji krakovi            |  0.9 |     24.2 |           2.9 |    119.5 |
|  5 | Ovčetina (srednje masno)  | 26.4 |     16.9 |           0.3 |      316 |
|  6 | Teletina                  |  4.5 |     19.5 |           0.3 |      123 |
|  7 | Puž                       |    1 |     17.6 |           0.2 |     82.3 |
|  8 | Pileći bataci             |  5.2 |     20.9 |           0.5 |    136.1 |
|  9 | Fazan                     |  1.9 |     22.3 |           0.5 |    111.2 |
| 10 | Trčka                     |  1.2 |     20.5 |           0.4 |     96.8 |
| 11 | Meso japanske prepelice   |    5 |     19.6 |           1.2 |    131.8 |
+----+---------------------------+------+----------+---------------+----------+
```

Let's say for example that my criterion is:
give me a list where I'm looking for 100 fat, 150 protein, 10 carbohydrates and 2000 calories

i should get a list where when I sump each individual attribute (fat,proteins,carbs,calories) does not exceed the given criteria

I don't even know how to start writing this query
any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output for the example of "100 fat, 150 protein, 10 carbohydrates and 2000 calories"?

Comment: You want to go over the table and give sets of food combination that doesn't exceed the criteria? Or you just want 1 set of food combination? How will you get what is first? Is there any order to get which food comes first?